# How can I pass combined URL as a parameter in android?

Tags: android, hashmap

I'm working on the music streaming service project. I like to show thumbnail jacket images when I started the application in the first place. 
I've fetched all the String Json results, and I've converted Jason results to hashmap by using Gson lib.
What I'm trying to do is combine the base url with map value and return? or pass the result, so that I can use the result with another thread in order to show the thumbnail images. please give me some answers..:(

MainActivity.java

```
private static final String baseURLforgetNewMusic = "https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/goblinsbucket/Artists/";
....
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    new Connection().execute(getMusicInfo_URL + "getNewMusic.php");
    // Connect to the server.
}

private class Connection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return getMusicInfo(urls[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
....

private String getMusicInfo(String url) {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String inputStr = "";

    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    try {
        URL getMusicUrl = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) getMusicUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        Log.d(TAGCP, "MADE POST REQUEST TO THE GIVEN URL");

        inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStr = Util.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            Log.i(TAGCS, inputStr);

            Music list = new Gson().fromJson(inputStr, Music.class);
            for (Music.MusicInfo info : list.musicInfo) {
                System.out.println(baseURLforgetNewMusic + info.artists
                        + "/" + info.file_name);
            }

        } else {
            inputStr = "Did not work!";
            Log.d(TAGRR, inputStr);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    return inputStr;

}

Results: (I want to use these url to show thumbnail images on the main view.)
I/System.out(22054): https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/goblinsbucket/Artists/BrunoMars/Grenade
I/System.out(22054): https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/goblinsbucket/Artists/BrunoMars/Justthewayyouare

I/System.out(22054): https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/goblinsbucket/Artists/Beenzino/Aquaman
I/System.out(22054): https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/goblinsbucket/Artists/Gummy/Thinkaboutme
```

Comment: I'm rather confused by what you have and what you want.  Show a sample of your data and what you want.

Comment: What is your problem? what do you have so far?

Comment: @AleksG         So far I fetched all the artist name and I've combined with base url. My problem is how to use those URLs to show the images? You can see the result url code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using volley to load your images. It will be faster and easier to use than Universal Image Loader. The library contains a class called NetworkImageView that will load all of your images for you.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but I still don't get the point. Could you please give tell me some useful example websites? I'm looking forward to my research skills.. what if I couldn't find it?

Comment: Also, my question was how to send those URLs so that I can use it in other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Try showing images with this library:

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

You can pass the list of URLs here and will show images in a gridview.

If you want to make something cool like CoverFlow for showing album covers use this:

https://github.com/Polidea/android-coverflow